# How to map values for entries which are not present and then fill those values with zero?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, null, group

I have data from [vaccinations data](https://github.com/ndoh-evds/evds-data-analytics/blob/main/Vaccination%20Data/2022-08-18/sacoronavirus_total_number_individuals_vaccinated_2022-08-18.csv) from South Africa which is in long format like below:
[image]

The possible entries for `age_group` are [image: age groups]
and for `sex` are Male or Female.

The data will be resampled monthly, how can I ensure (map values) to ensure that for each month for each district, there are all age_groups present (sometimes "Unidentified" is not present so it would be to fill the "Unidentified" for both Female and Male and then fill the total_number_individuals_vaccinated value with zero)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
df[„age_groups“].fillna(„Unidentified“)
```

and

```
df[„total_number_individuals_vaccinated“].fillna(0)
```

Comment: thaat would not help. for the example above, if 18-34, 35-49,550-59,60+ are present but unidentified is not present (not inthe data for that district)

Answer (score 0):

Each time you'll recieve new data. You can use:

```
df_new.loc[:, 'age_group'].nunique()
```

or

```
df_new.loc[:, 'age_group'].value_counts()
```

to verify the categories. You can check the official pandas api documentation for both functions [.value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [.unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html)

When you'll receive a new set of data. Let's call it `df_new` after reading it. You can fill NaN values using:

```
df_new.loc[:, 'age_group'] = df_new.loc[:, 'age_group'].fillna("Unidentified")
```

You can also do the same for the `total_number_individuals_vaccinated` column

```
df_new.loc[:, 'total_number_individuals_vaccinated'] = df_new.loc[:, 'total_number_individuals_vaccinated'].fillna("Unidentified")
```

Then, you can concat your new data with past ones.

```
df = pd.concat([df_past, df_new], axis=1)
```